# Delete an element from a list while iterating in R

Tags: r, list, iteration

I have this R function where i make some computations like average and median of such values comes from a website. `fromTime` and `toTime` are two dates in a string format like 2020-10-12. `computationType` is a string that specify the type of computation like average or median. `new_suri` is a serviceUri (string) and `sensor` is also a string. I have a problem in the second `for` (that is the same in the second part of the function) where i do this:
Take the "i" element of `value` and add this element to another list called `valori`. After this check if there is some error in this "i" element. If some of the conditions in the `if` statement is met then remove the "i" element from `valori`.
I would like the element to be deleted and then the list to return to its original length. The length I would have had without that element. But i obtain the error that you can see below

```
dayHour <- function(fromTime,toTime,dayOfTrend,computationType,new_suri,sensor){
  errorList <- list()
  valori <- vector(mode = "double")
  dayHourValues <- list()
  dayOTList <- list()
  hour <- c("00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23")
  interval <- as_date(ymd(fromTime):ymd(toTime)) # giorni presenti tra le due date "fromTime" e "toTime"
  for(a in 1:length(interval)) {
    if(strftime(interval[[a]], '%A') == dayOfTrend){
      element <- as.character.Date(interval[[a]])
      dayOTList <- c(dayOTList, element) # Lista dei giorni che servono per calcolare il trend in funzione del dayOfTrend (es. tutti i lunedì)
    }
  }
  
  for (j in 1:length(hour)) {
    if (j == 24){
      for (y in 1:length(dayOTList)) {
        from <- paste(hour[[j]],":00:00", sep = "")
        to <- paste(hour[[j]],":59:59", sep = "")
        fromDateTime <- paste(dayOTList[[y]],"T",hour[[j]],":00:00", sep = "") #yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss
        toDateTime <- paste(dayOTList[[y]],"T",hour[[j]],":59:59", sep = "") #yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss
        
        # Costruisco la query per ottenere i dati richiesti
        api <- paste("SERVICEURI",
                     new_suri,
                     "&valueName=",
                     sensor,
                     "&fromTime=",
                     fromDateTime,
                     "&toTime=",
                     toDateTime,
                     sep="")
        
        # Invio la chiamata e la parso sotto forma di JSON in res
        res <- fromJSON(api)
        
        # Prendo il blocco di valori che contiene quel sensore
        value <- res$realtime$results$bindings
        # Estrapolo il valore richiesto che si trova sotto il nome di sensor
        value <- getElement(value,sensor)
        
        
        for (i in 1:length(value)) {
          valori <- c(valori,as.numeric(value[[i]]))
          if (is.na(valori[[i]])){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(is.null(valori[[i]])){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(sensor == "averageSpeed" & valori[[i]] >= 130){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(sensor == "concentration" & valori[[i]] >= 900){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(sensor == "vehicleFlow" & valori[[i]] >= 900){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value", "\n")
          }else{
            print("All is ok!")
          }
        }
    valori <- valori[!str_detect(valori, pattern = "error")]
        
      }
      if(computationType == "average"){
        computedValues <- mean(valori) # calcolo la media dei valori nell'intervallo orario per ogni data presente nella lista
      }else{
        computedValues <- median(valori) # calcolo la mediana dei valori nell'intervallo orario per ogni data presente nella lista
      }
      valori <- vector(mode = "double") # pulisco la lista che deve contenere gli altri valori per una nuova fascia oraria
      dayHourValues <- c(dayHourValues,computedValues)
      computedValues <- list()
    }else{
      for (y in 1:length(dayOTList)) {
        from <- paste(hour[[j]],":00:00", sep = "")
        to <- paste(hour[[j+1]],":00:00", sep = "")
        fromDateTime <- paste(dayOTList[[y]],"T",from, sep = "") #Tyyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss
        toDateTime <- paste(dayOTList[[y]],"T",to, sep = "") #Tyyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss
        
        # Costruisco la query per ottenere i dati richiesti
        api <- paste("SERVICEURI=",
                     new_suri,
                     "&valueName=",
                     sensor,
                     "&fromTime=",
                     fromDateTime,
                     "&toTime=",
                     toDateTime,
                     sep="")
        
        # Invio la chiamata e la parso sotto forma di JSON in res
        res <- fromJSON(api)
        
        # Prendo il blocco di valori che contiene quel sensore
        value <- res$realtime$results$bindings
        # Estrapolo il valore richiesto che si trova sotto il nome di sensor
        value <- getElement(value,sensor) 
        
        for (i in 1:length(value)) {
          valori <- c(valori,as.numeric(value[[i]]))
          if (is.na(valori[[i]])){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(is.null(valori[[i]])){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(sensor == "averageSpeed" & valori[[i]] >= 130){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(sensor == "concentration" & valori[[i]] >= 900){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value")
          }else if(sensor == "vehicleFlow" & valori[[i]] >= 900){
            valori[[i]] <- paste("error", sep = "")
            errorList <- c(errorList,"In this time span: ",dayOTList[[y]],":",from, " to ", to, " there is a wrong value", "\n")
          }else{
            print("All is ok!")
          }
        }
    valori <- valori[!str_detect(valori, pattern = "error")]

        
      }
      if(computationType == "average"){
        computedValues <- mean(valori) # calcolo la media dei valori nell'intervallo orario per ogni data presente nella lista
      }else{
        computedValues <- median(valori) # calcolo la mediana dei valori nell'intervallo orario per ogni data presente nella lista
      }
      valori <- vector(mode = "double") # pulisco la lista che deve contenere gli altri valori per una nuova fascia oraria
      dayHourValues <- c(dayHourValues,computedValues)
      computedValues <- list()
    }
  }
  
  return(returnList <- list("values" = dayHourValues, "error" = errorList)) # Ritorna lista dei 24 valori tipici 
}
```

And now i obtain this error:

```
Error in valori[[i]] <- NULL : replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(value[[i]])) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (sensor == "averageSpeed" & value[[i]] >= 130) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Update:
I solved the first problem, but now the problem is this:

```
[1] "All is ok!"
[1] "All is ok!"
[1] "All is ok!"
Error in valori[[i]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

So i think that the problem is something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30020466/error-in-lisi-attempt-to-select-less-than-one-element)

Comment: At least in base R, you can't delete a value from a list like that. Also, there are several other problems in your code. We can better help you if you give us a richer context. For instance, what are your `y`, `from` and `to`? They don't even exist in your for loop. If you call them like that, you will likely get the same repeated message for every iteration.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the code. I want that when an element of the vector "valori" satisfy one of these condition then a line is added in errorList vector

Comment: We can hardly help you with such limited information. As we have no idea what `valori` looks like, nor can we know what is your `sensor`, `from`, `to` or `value`. Please read about [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/10802499) and update your question with the necessary information for us to work on.

Comment: Ok thanks, following the guidelines i edited the original question.